# Git: remove compiled executables to prune

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to delete/remove compiled files, which where commited. My repository takes up more than 500mb space. Running git clean, or git prune seems to be only taming the issue, in the sense of stronger compression, not removing any bigger files like those executables i'm talking about - therefore the size stays ruffly the same. The plain code in itself does not compare to the accumulated size of the executables throughout the commits.

Afterwards I want to push the git repository, without the history of it being lost for the code i've written. I do not care about the executables.